# Limit of Subexponential Sequence

Tags: limits

I am reading a paper that contains the following limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{log(a_n)}{n}$$

where we have the following growth control on $a_n$:

$a_{n+m} \leq a_n  a_m$.

I am trying to prove that the above limit exists, using this fact (according to the paper it is supposed to be easy, but I'm not seeing it). I was also told that the fact that this limit exists is a standard argument, but I can't find any material on sequences that grow sub-exponentially.

I was hoping that I could get some hints or references. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fekete's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity) is the standard "easy" result.  The $a_m$ sequence is *sub-multiplicative* and $\log a_m$ is *sub-additive*.

Comment: Ah it even has a name, so it really is standard, thank you!